# Script Is not working inside bootstrap template contentplaceholder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

This is my master page form code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Candidate Page</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">


            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">


                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Manage Profile<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://localhost:5529/candidate/CandidateProfile.aspx">Personal Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://localhost:5529/candidate/Academic.aspx">Academic</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://localhost:5529/candidate/ProExperience.aspx">Professional Experience</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost:5529/candidate/UploadResume.aspx"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Upload Resume</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost:5529/candidate/ChangePW.aspx"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Change Password</a>
                    </li>                                            

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">

             <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_title" runat="server">

                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder></h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_content" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                 </div>
        </div>

     </div>
     <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="/../js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="/../js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="/../js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</div>
</form>
```

this is my content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
```

> href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
>
> $(function () {
>          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
>              changeMonth: true,
>              changeYear: true
>          });
>      });
>
> Institude/University
>               Graduate Date

```
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">Highest Education level</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">Field of Study</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEducation" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilStudy" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">Grade</td>
        <td class="auto-style1"><input id="datepicker" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrade" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4"></td>
        <td class="auto-style5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: what i want to do is call the 'datepicker' and a calender will pop up.
but when do it in new masterpage, these code work fine(so i assume script is no problem), but when i apply to the masterpage frame contentpage 'cph_content', the script no works.

Comment: Well, you are using `head` for the `ContentPlaceHolderID`, but I don't see that anywhere in your Master Page.

Comment: stackoverflow was not allow me to put whole code in here, so i only put part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.Just for other who probably facing same issue to refer.there are few things to check.

1. check the **JQuery** version in the master page was compatible with the Link's version.
2. try to change the **panel control**'s ID (button,input,...) to avoid the reserved key-word duplicated.
3. vote me if it is helped. =P